# Using IS NOT NULL and IS NULL as parameters in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I am creating an SSRS report where I need to have a parameter called Status and the values would be "Current", "Former", or basically selecting both of them in terms of display both Current and Former.

This parameter will reference a date column and if the `(date is NULL OR date > GETDATE())` then they would be considered "Current"

If `(date is not NULL AND date < GETDATE())` then they would be considered "Former"

I've tried using in the WHERE clause `(WHERE DATE @NULL OR DATE > GETDATE())` and similarly with the "Former" parameter value, but I am not sure if in SSRS if it's possible to pass the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL to these parameter values.

Sample of table data:

```
Name     Date
John     NULL
Bill     2/27/2021
Bob      2/1/2021
```

So in this example, John is "Current", Bill is still "Current", and Bob is "Former".

Comment: If date < GETDATE() is true, there's no need to check for date is not NULL.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and add an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Context is important. What exactly do you mean by "basically selecting both of them"? Is your parameter "optional" and that you want to include everything when this parameter is "not set"?

Comment: The parameter would be required and if we were to choose to select both "Current" and "Former", it would display results for both current and former employees based on the date column.

Comment: A (singular) parameter cannot contain multiple values ("Current" and "Former"). Your report parameter is likely a string - do you intend to embed both of those words in it somehow? And then how is that parameter used within the datasource of the report? Without context, it will be difficult for people to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
WHERE (@param = 'Current' AND (Date is NULL OR date > GETDATE()))
 OR (@param = 'Former' AND Date <= GETDATE())
 OR @param = 'All'
```

As jarlh said, you don't need to check for "is not null and less than" in the second line.

Not sure what you meant by "basically selecting both of them" so I assumed a third option for "all". If the parameter being null triggers that instead, you should be able to change the last line to:

```
OR @param is NULL
```

Then "NULL IS NULL" would satisfy the third condition and bring back all rows.